# How can I create a desktop shortcut for a winforms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, shortcut-file

I have a winform application and it has several panels for a task and a "run" button that will start a windows service on click. How can I create a desktop shortcut to start that will run the windows service task?

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Service programmatically, or how to start a Service you coded, as part of your Solution? What is a *winforms application panel*? What is a *task*, here? IMO. it's not clear what a *desktop shortcut* is supposed to start.

Comment: I have a winform application which has multiple panels and a run button. when i click on the run button , it starts a windows service and does some operation. Now I want to add a desktop shortcut for that run button so that the user doesnt have to login to application and click run, he can use the desktop shortcut to start win service. hope this helps to explain the question

Comment: All right. Now, do you need to create a Shortcut programmatically, or just provide a pre-built Shortcut that runs, say, `net start [someservice]`, or should it run an executable of yours (with a specific commandline) that uses, say, `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` to start a service and then quits?

Comment: I need to create a shortcut programmatically, when the user says create a desktop shortcut for this panel and its properties, he should be able to run the service from that shortcut.

Comment: Add to your Project a reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model` and `using IWshRuntimeLibrary;`, then run this:  `string shortcutPath = @"[SomePath].lnk"; var wShell = new WshShell(); var wLink = (IWshShortcut)wShell.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath); wLink.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath; wLink.Arguments = "start serviceName"; wLink.Save();`. **`serviceName`** would be the name of the service to start. See whether **`[SomePath].lnk`** is created and runs your executable. If it works work you, I'll post the rest.

Comment: Can I call a method in wLink.Arguments? I have a method in which it would launch the application, login with credentials and then start the service. Is there a way to pass the method directly? How can I call this method when the user opens the shortcut?

Comment: If the shortcut is meant to run your application (or a satellite executable you use just for this), you pass some command line parameters to the `Arguments` property. These parameters are passed to the application, as usual, in `Main(args[])`. You can also use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to get the arguments passed to the executable. In this case, the first argument is the path of the executable itself, then the parameters specified in the `Arguments` property. You then run a method based on what arguments you receive, as usual.

Comment: private void CreateRunTaskShortcut()
        {
            object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            string shortcutPath = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Task1.lnk";
            var wLink = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath);
            wLink.TargetPath = @"C:\Program Files\Receiver.exe";
            wLink.Arguments = //Need to pass my method here//;
            wLink.Save();
        } what should i pass in the comment section? here's my method. LoginAndRunTask(task);

Comment: `string shortcutPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Task1.lnk");`. `wLink.TargetPath` cannot point to `"C:\Program Files\"`. Use what I posted before. As already mentioned, you cannot pass a *method* in the arguments: when you read the arguments, you see what's been passed on, then call a method depending on what arguments you have received. E.g., if `args[1] = "start"`, then you know that you have to call a method that starts a service and the name of the service to start is in `args[2]` (if you use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general problem description, so I can only give a general answer:

1. Make the programm a single Instance. Those solutions usually have a way to get informations from one start attempt to the already running instance (like wich Word Document that 2nd Word instance was supposed to open, so the already running one can deal with that).
2. Make a shortcut to the programm with a proper Commandline Parameter for "Start with Service".
3. Unpack "start with Service" order before the Single-Instance check. Relay the call to the already running instance.